# Ubuntu 15.10 Wireless problem

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 15.10, atheros

Today I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I can't using internet with wireless connection. In connection information is written that I'm connected, but I can't do anything. When I'm connected with cable everything is well. I tried to connect my WiFi dongle, which I'm using in raspberry pi and everything is working aswell.
Here is my ifconfig with WiFi dongle:

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:2d:50:42:db  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:247229 (247.2 KB)  TX bytes:247229 (247.2 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:c4:b5:11:06  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:413 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18927 (18.9 KB)  TX bytes:44320 (44.3 KB)

wlx243c200d02b2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:3c:20:0d:02:b2  
          inet addr:192.168.0.109  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::263c:20ff:fe0d:2b2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11258 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10695403 (10.6 MB)  TX bytes:1594026 (1.5 MB)
```

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net command output:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0207]
Kernel driver in use: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Quanta Microsystems, Inc EM306 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [AR9283] [1a32:0306]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

lshw -c net command output:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:26:2d:50:42:db
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=sb v2.19 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:32 memory:f4100000-f410ffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:17:c4:b5:11:06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.3.3-040303-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f4200000-f420ffff
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14257243/

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/713044/edit) the question to include results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`  Thanks

Comment: DId the wireless connection worked when installing ubuntu?

Comment: @albertoefg It wasn't working.

Comment: Is your wifi access point using WPA2 encryption only or is it using a mixed mode. check `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'`  Find your access points name and see if the group and pairwise ciphers show CCMP only

Comment: @Jeremy31 I'vr got no encryption and iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher' giving no cipher on my access point

Comment: It should work with the cable and dongle disconnected.  With the cable disconnected and the dongle unplugged run `lshw -c net` reconnect to the internet and edit your post to include results

Comment: @Jeremy31 Okay.

Comment: It looks like it should work.  Please take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and paste the results at paste.ubuntu.com and add the URL to your question

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your country code and the script results would indicate you are in Poland

```
sudo iw reg set PL
```

Then we will change the crda file
`gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda`

The last line of the file needs to be

`REGDOMAIN=PL`

Save file and exit gedit.  Then use Network Manager connection settings and set the IPv6 to ignore for your connection and in IPv4 settings add DNS of 8.8.8.8 and save.  Reboot and see if you can have any connectivity

Comment: I can ping myself but not access point or other devices.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf `

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: Try booting into the 4.2 kernel as I don't think 4.3 is an Ubuntu kernel

Comment: Now I'm using 4.2 kernel and it's not working. I tried manually config and it wasn't working too.

Comment: Installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and eveything is working well.